# VAGRANT UP not working when executed via BAMBOO

Tags: vagrant, bamboo

I am trying to work with Vagrant and Bamboo together. I created custom box which I put on a web server from which it is getting downloaded when doing `vagrant up`. When I do it manually on the computer everything goes as expected.

When I try this via Bamboo however, the folder for local box in `c:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.vagrant.d\boxes` is not created and subsequently fails as vagrant is not able to do import.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/k.box'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "-n", "C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/.vagrant.d/boxes/http-VAGRANTCOLON--VAGRANTSLASH--VAGRANTSLASH-127.0.0.1-VAGRANTCOLON-8000-VAGRANTSLASH-k.box/0/virtualbox/box.ovf"]

Stderr: 0%...

Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR

VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance read failed

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not read OVF file 'box.ovf' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)

VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance

VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 307 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Did any of you encountered similar problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I found the reason for this. The problem is that by default `.vagrant.d` folder is created in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile` when the vagrant is run via Bamboo. This is the folder where the boxes are stored after download.
The `PROFILEUSER` environment variable is set to `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`for `SYSTEM` user. Subsequently after downloading the box it went to look for it into `.vagrant.d` folder inside `PROFILEUSER` folder instead of the one that really stored the box.

This problem was solved by setting `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.vagrant.d`. After this, vagrant looks into correct folder for stored boxes.